# onreadystatechange only called when blocked by alert()

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, xmlhttprequest, contextmenu

I have a simple javascript html file that I am using to perform a function that is called from menu item that I added to the Internet Explorer default context menu (through windows registry). The menu click triggers the following javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") 
 req.onreadystatechange = function() {

 if (req.readyState == 4) {
        if (req.status == 200) {
            var serverResponse = req.responseText;
            alert(serverResponse); // Shows "15"
        }
     }
 };

 req.open("POST", "https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=myAPIkey", true)
 req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json")
 req.send('{"longUrl": "https://bing.com"}')

</script>
```

If I run this by opening the html file in IE it works fine. I get the response text. However, if I load it through the Context Menu the "onreadystatechange" function is never called.

If I add "alert("test") to the end of my script the test alert pops up followed a fraction of a second later by the serverResponse alert. I assume it has something to do with the alert blocking or forcing the browser to do something but I can't figure out why it works when loaded as a page but not through the Context menu.

I should note that the rest of the script DOES get called, so I know the menu item is working.

**EDIT:**

The above code snippet runs and displays an alert dialog containing the text of the response from the server whenever it's executed as an html page. If executed through the context menu I never get the "alert(serverResponse)".

However the following version does work when called from the context menu:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP") 
 req.onreadystatechange = function() {

 if (req.readyState == 4) {
        if (req.status == 200) {
            var serverResponse = req.responseText;
            alert(serverResponse); // Shows "15"
        }
     }
 };

 req.open("POST", "https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=myAPIkey", true)
 req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json")
 req.send('{"longUrl": "https://bing.com"}')

 alert("test")

</script>
```

The only difference is the inclusion of the "alert("Test")" line at the end

Comment: It is not clear to me what the code looks like when it works and what the code looks like when it doesn't work.  Please make that more clear in the code you show.  An `alert()` can hide mistakes in how you handle an asynchronous response, but to advise you further, we need to understand better what the code looks like when it works and what it looks like when it doesn't and what "not working" means exactly.

Comment: What does "called from the context menu" mean?  Is there code associated with that?

Comment: No, no code. I'm simply following this guide: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/05/24/140283.aspx